# how do you increment a irregular time series data in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

dput(test)

```
structure(1376661600, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

I need to increment this value by one hour if the time is greater than 07:00 and less than 13:00 and date is in M-F.

Is there somesort of package that I can use to do this?

Comment: That's not a `data.frame`.  Do you really have a `data.frame`, or just a `POSIXct` vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# A data.frame with a .POSIXct column
d <- data.frame(x = .POSIXct(0, tz="GMT") + 6:14*60*60)
d
#                    x
#1 1970-01-01 06:00:00
#2 1970-01-01 07:00:00
#3 1970-01-01 08:00:00
#4 1970-01-01 09:00:00
#5 1970-01-01 10:00:00
#6 1970-01-01 11:00:00
#7 1970-01-01 12:00:00
#8 1970-01-01 13:00:00
#9 1970-01-01 14:00:00

# get the hours
hour <- as.POSIXlt(d[["x"]])$hour
subsetBool <- hour > 7 & hour < 13 # a logical vector to use for subsetting
# replace subset with subset + 1 hour
d[["x"]][subsetBool] <- d[["x"]][subsetBool] + 60 * 60 
d
#                    x
#1 1970-01-01 06:00:00
#2 1970-01-01 07:00:00
#3 1970-01-01 09:00:00
#4 1970-01-01 10:00:00
#5 1970-01-01 11:00:00
#6 1970-01-01 12:00:00
#7 1970-01-01 13:00:00
#8 1970-01-01 13:00:00
#9 1970-01-01 14:00:00
```